# Create PDF Reports with a previous design for all records (Or selected ones) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf, reports

I have 3 different point layers in a project, they share an ID (they are trees and each tree has same ID in all layers). I would like to know how can I create a PDF with a combination of attribute information from all layers (maybe in different tables and little map if possible). I would like to generate a PDF for each tree automatically without having to customize every tree or PDF one by one manually.

Comment: It seem you are looking for the atlas functionality : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html#generate-an-atlas

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i was looking for! I am now into the proccess to learn how Atlas works and i am doing quite a good progress but i have still some concerns like, how can i add like a table frame where i can write down every single attribute from one row for each page? I dont wanna add the whole attribute table as i want the Atlas to show an item for page. I dont know if i make myself understandable enough. Thanks for you comments